# Comparing two data sets with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 data set objects and would like to return `true` if the same `id` exists in both objects.

I tried implementing it using the ES6 feature `some` but couldn't get it to work.

```js
datalog1 = [{
  "id": 12501,
  "addedOn": "2019-02-04T16:49:09.3245844+00:00"
}, {
  "id": 12498,
  "addedOn": "2019-02-04T15:48:38.8310577+00:00"
}]
datalog2 = [{
  "id": 12501,
  "addedOn": "2019-02-04T15:19:54.3464314+00:00"
}]

let found = dataLog1.some(dataLog => dataLog.includes(dataLog2))

console.log(found)
```

Comment: `datalog` is an object. `.some` is an Array method. Actually scratch that. What type is `datalog`?

Comment: @user10609979 please give more info and expected output

Comment: Also dataLog2 consists of all the same keys but I guess you added that as an example. Looking at the data it makes no sense to be an object. Better to provide data which actually works rather than pseudo data.

Comment: Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(dataLog))` instead of copying and pasting what's shown in your console. It will be easier to identify the structure of your data.

Comment: Your dataLog2 has all the same keys which is invalid in objects.

Comment: Please also include any errors that are showing up when you try these things.

Comment: I fixed your arrays and created a snippet with a [mcve]. Your syntax is off even after fixing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using `0,1,2,..` for keys of objects.You should use `Arrays`.You can loop through each item of `dataLog` and find if its id exists in any `dataLog2` item

```js
const dataLog = [
  {id: 12489, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"},
  {id: 12489, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"},
  {id: 12489, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"},
  {id: 12489, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"},
  {id: 12489, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"},
  {id: 12489, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"}
]


const dataLog2 =[
  {id: 12489, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"},
  {id: 15000, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"},
  {id: 15100, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"},
  {id: 15200, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"},
  {id: 15300, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"},
  {id: 15400, addedOn: "2019-02-04T15:19:54"}
]
function compare(data1,data2){
  for(let item of data1){
    if(data2.find(item2 => item2.id === item.id)) return true 
  }
  return false
}
console.log(compare(dataLog,dataLog2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Naive approach as long as your data set is not too large due to iterating the other data set every iteration. And assuming what you posted is incorrect and you're actually talking about **arrays of objects** (I'm guessing so as it looks like it would make a lot more sense as an array):

```
const found = dataLog.some(item => dataLog2.some(item2 => item2.id === item.id))
```